# Where's diff in Xcode 11?

Tags: xcode, git-diff, xcode11

In previous versions it was so easy to get difference between my code and code from any specific commit. But where is this button in Xcode 11?! There is only Authors button.
[image]

Comment: Upper right corner, the one with the two arrows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to click on button with two arrows on top right corner:

[image]

Comment: This button with arrows is above *Editor options* with *Authors* button. I updated my answer with bigger screenshot :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to select *View* > *Show code review*